# Build ember-cli addon without dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I developed an ember-cli addon that works fine.

When I run the command `ember build`, it basically creates a `vendor.js` file that contains my addon and all dependencies (ember, jquery etc...) which is about 3MB

I'd like to know if it's possible to export the addon as its own (`my-addon.js`) without any dependencies inside, as a vendor I can use?

I'm basically trying to make my ember-cli addon a bower component that I can include in another ember project.
My addon and all dependencies are more than 100MB of data (including node modules, broccoli, tests...), so when I install it using npm install my-addon, it's pretty big. I don't really need that in my other project, the addon itself (dist version) is about a couple of KB and that's all I need...

Basically, this is the architecture of my projects:

Ember project:

*my-project.git*

```
/my-project
  /app
    /controllers etc...
  /node_modules
    /my-addon //My addon lives here for now and contains everything (all node_modules, bower_components, tests... about 100MB to download!)
  Brocfile.js etc..
```

Basic architecture for an ember-cli addon:

*my-addon.git*

```
/my-addon
  /addon
  /app
  /bower_components
  /node_modules
  /tests
  Brocfile.js etc..
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-addon",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "directories": {
        "doc": "doc",
        "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
        "start": "ember server",
        "build": "ember build",
        "test": "ember test"
  },
  "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.2.0",
        "broccoli-sass": "0.3.2",
        "broccoli-asset-rev": "0.3.1",
        "broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.6.1",
        "ember-cli": "0.1.2",
        "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.3.0",
        "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.1.1",
        "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.0",
        "ember-cli-qunit": "0.1.0",
        "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.10",
        "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.0",
        "express": "^4.8.5",
        "glob": "^4.0.5"
    }
    "keywords": [
        "ember-addon"
    ],

    "ember-addon": {
        "configPath": "tests/dummy/config"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you point us in the direction of your addon's repo

Comment: I edited the post with the architecture of the projects.

Comment: I am more interested in the package.json file that your addon has for managing dependencies and such

Comment: I added what the package.json of my addon looks like.

Comment: Could you jump on the ember js IRC channel or the [SO channel](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63494/ember-js)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64502/discussion-between-tilix-and-patsy-issa).

Answer (score 0):

So, what happened?

My answer would be, that your local repo - should have all that junk that it needs to process etc... but the final code that you set up with bower, should be a either a branch with just your /dist or something or - the github repo should only have the unbuilt code. Then... you `bower install --save your-thing` - which would then get registered with the ember app. then just `bower install` or `update` etc - and it will check the config - and pull in the dependencies based on the `package.json` and the `bower.json`.

It would be great if you documented your findings and answered this question here. I bet it's a pretty common workflow.